# How to click a link that opens a sign in page on another page/window using Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, ide, selenium

Newbie here, I'm trying to get the value of a link using document.getelementbyClass/Name & then navigate to the page the link points to in a different window/tab using Selenium IDE.

All suggestions gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Is there any reason you can't use the `click` command on the link? Perhaps some example HTML would help.

Comment: thanks Dave for d response, was previously getting a 'link contains target=_blank + selenium does not support this... error msg. Solved this by getting a later version of SIDE. I can now click said link, i need help switching to the new page i've been directed to which is on a different tab, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple using TestPlan as a front-end to Selenium. In the scripting language it might look something like the below.

```
GotoURL http://mypage.com/
set %Link% as response //*[@name='myname']/@href
GotoURL %Link%
```

Using multiple windows requires a few sub-scripts, but it isn't too hard to do once you have the basics working.  You can also use the HTMLUnit backend to test since it is faster than using Selenium.

Comment: thanks edA-qa mort-ora-y, having worked out how to store the link's text(a url) and open a new window with it i'm now faced with the problem of selecting this new window. All head ups gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the window, you can use the [selectwindow](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow(java.lang.String))